# Excel VBA to average based on a time range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of values (Column B) that have a timestamp (Column A) in hh:mm:ss: AM/PM format. What I am trying to do is average the values in Column B for every 10 minutes past in Column A. For example, I would need to average all the values in Column A from 12:40:00 PM - 12:50:00 PM in Column B. Ideally the code could scan through the entire dataset to produce these 10 minute averages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you attempted anything or just asking for someone to code the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this as a vba question, but the result can be easily achieved with a formula.

If you are using Excel 2007 or later, use the `AVERAGEIFS` function

```
=AverageIfS(B:B,A:A,">="&<StartTime>,A:A,"<"&(<StartTime>+10/1440))
```

Replace `<StartTime>` with a reference to a cell containing the beginning of your 10min period.

Comment: You have saved me an exorbitant amount of time. Thank you kind sir